# laravel: gloval value to be used on every view

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a login site with laravel. Is there a way that I can store the user's name on a variable where it can be called on the page?

I know I can store it in a session like 
`Session::put('loginName', Auth::user()->name);`

but this then I would have to also retrieve this user's name on every controller using 
    `$loginName = Session::get('loginName');
    return View::make('dashboard/index')->with('loginName', $loginName);`

and to get it from the view file with
    `{{$loginName}}`

I just wonder if there is a short cut so I don't have to repeat this on every controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.php` file, do this:

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $name = Auth::user()->name;
}else{
    $name = 'Guest';
}
View::share('name', $name);
```

In your view files:

```
{{ $name }}
```